# List of world countries, states and their counties / districts / regions

Tags: states, regions, countries

Please suggest sites for downloading list of world countries, states and their counties / districts / regions.

No need for cities.

Comment: did you find a database with this?, because im a stuck too getting a database with states, countries and cities

Answer (score 12):

go to : [www.maxmind.com](http://www.maxmind.com) it's free and 99.5% accurate.

```
EDIT:

IP: 34.133.14.7
country: US - United States
state/region: TX - Texas
city: Houston
zip: 77072
lat/lon: 29.6997 / -95.5858
```

Comment: From www.maxmind.com  I will get data upto city level. But I need details of counties/districts/regions in each state.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Yahoo Geo technologies](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/) or Wiki location API.

You can also have a look at [programmableweb](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Mapping) for other Mapping APIs

Comment: The Yahoo GeoPlanet API can fetch counties, but when I tried it wasn't working correctly.  Their example correctly fetches 58 counties for CA (California), but in real-life I'm getting all kinds of things relating to Canada.  Bummer.  http://www.sba.gov/about-sba-services/7617 seems to work pretty well, not fully tested yet.